# How to convert Bystream Video to file video in java

Tags: java, encryption, stream, io, filestream

I'm build a project to convert video to byte stream, doing some encryption, and convert agaian stream that have been encrypting into video file. I am using mpeg video..

Anybody know how to convert from byte stream to file video? in case, mpeg file...thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a file into a byte stream, simply open it using FileInputStream.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("filename.mov");
```

You'll probably want to buffer it as video files are quite large

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (fis);
```

To write out the file, simply open it using FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("fileout.mov");
```

and then write to it using the FileOutputStream.